# Accessing db3 file path from S3 bucket using boto3 and Python

Tags: python, sqlite, amazon-s3, boto3

My usecase requires me to access db3 files from S3 bucket and store the data to the database. I have written a function to extract db3 files. For this, the parameter I have to pass is the link of db3 file path to the user-defined function that I wrote. How can I know the path of files on S3? Or is there any other way I can do this? I have already established the connection to S3 using boto3 and am able to view all file names.

My user-defined function is to read ros bag files

```
def read_bag_file(path_to_db3file):
    Code to extract and store information to the database
```

S3 connection

```
s3 = boto3.resource(
    service_name='s3',
    region_name='us-west-2',
    aws_access_key_id='access ID',
    aws_secret_access_key='Key'
)

for obj in s3.Bucket('test-bagfiles').objects.all():
    print(obj.key)
```

When I print obj.key I get the file paths. One of the path is

```
bagfiles/bag_9998_central_2021_08_1218_33_49_d58fec5/bag_9998_central_2021_8_12-18_33_49_d58fec5_0.db3
```

I would now like to pass this db3 file path to the read_bag_file code to extract information and store it in the database. How can I pass this bagfile location to the read_bag_file function?

Comment: Can you show the code that demonstrates your issue and what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to concatenate the bucket and key

```
bucket = 'test-bagfiles'

for obj in s3.Bucket(bucket).objects.all():
    read_bag_file(bucket + '/' + obj.key)
```